# dynamic radio button behaviour with knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radio-button

I have a button to create radio buttons like this:

```
<input value="&uparrow;" type="button" data-bind=" click: moveUp"/>
<input value="&downarrow;" type="button" data-bind="click: moveDown"/>
<input data-bind="value: selectedradio" />
<div data-bind="foreach: radios">
    <div data-bind="attr:{id:radioid} ">
       <input type="radio" name="group" data-bind="value:radioid, checked:$parent.selectedradio"/>
     </div>
</div>
<div>
     <input type="button" value="+" data-bind="click: addRadio"/>
</div>
```

when the radio buttons are created they are each assigned a unique index and i have bound the checked attribute to a property on the parent called `selectedradio`

I am able to modify `selectedradio` though an html input and the selected radio will change but If I modify the value progmmatically it will not.

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8vVeU/

here is the javascript for reference:

```
function Radio(id){
    this.radioid = ko.observable(id);
}

 function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.selectedradio = ko.observable(0);
        self.radios = ko.observableArray([new Radio(0),new Radio(1),new Radio(2),new Radio(3)]);

        self.addRadio = function() {
            self.radios.push(new Radio());
            self.reIndex();
         };
         self.moveUp = function() {
            self.selectedradio(self.selectedradio()-1)
            self.reIndex();
          };
        self.moveDown = function() {
            self.selectedradio(self.selectedradio()+1)
            self.reIndex();
          };

        self.reIndex = function() {
            $.each(self.radios(), function(i, r) {
                r.radioid(i);             
          });
        }


}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of radio buttons the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) by default compares the input's `value` attribute - which is a string - to the model property.

So you need to store **strings** in your `selectedradio` :

```
self.moveUp = function(r) {
    r=parseInt(r,10);
    self.selectedradio((parseInt(self.selectedradio())-1).toString())
    self.reIndex();
};
self.moveDown = function(r) {
    r=parseInt(r,10);
    self.selectedradio((parseInt(self.selectedradio())+1).toString())
    self.reIndex();
};
```

It works with the textbox because it will fill in the `selectedradio` with the entered string.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WvZK8/).

Or you can change the default behavior and you can tell KO to use a different property as the checkbox's value with the `checkedValue` option:

```
<input type="radio" name="group" data-bind="value:radioid, 
       checked:$parent.selectedradio, checkedValue: radioid"/>
```

In this case you don't need to alter your `moveUp` and `moveDown` methods because now the `selectedradio` will always contain integers however because your textbox still sets the `selectedradio` to string it won't work any more.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zn54K/).

Comment: Thanks I didn't really care about the text input it was just there to help explain the scenario